# How To use Two models in Action Controller

Tags: magento2

I have made my own grid for a contact form,
in that add new contact controller is shown below

```
<?php
namespace 
My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use My\Module\Model\Save as Contact;

class NewAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * Edit A Contact Page
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();

    $contactDatas = $this->getRequest()->getParam('contact');
    if(is_array($contactDatas)) {
        $contact = $this->_objectManager->create(Contact::class);
        $contact->setData($contactDatas)->save();
        if($contact->save()){
             $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the data.'));
        }else{
             $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Data was not saved.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
    }
}
}
```

in this i have fields like firstname, lastname, phone, email, address, zipcode, country.
i want to store fristname, lastname, phone, email on table my_module_contact that is working very well in this code
but value of address, zipcode, and country i want in other table 
how to do,
can any one HELP

Comment: You can add a separate model for saving remaining data to another table and use your code to saving the data

Comment: i have separate model, but can you explain code for that since i am new to coding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code

```
<?php
namespace 
My\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Test;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use My\Module\Model\Save as Contact;
use My\Module\Model\SecondModel; // Second Model

class NewAction extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * Edit A Contact Page
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page|\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
 */
public function execute()
{
    $this->_view->loadLayout();
    $this->_view->renderLayout();

    $contactDatas = $this->getRequest()->getParam('contact');
    $secondDatas = //data you want to save
    if(is_array($contactDatas)) {
        //Second Model Data
        $secondModel = $this->_objectManager->create(SeconModel::class);
        $secondModel->setData($secondDatas)->save();   
        // also check condition for save

        $contact = $this->_objectManager->create(Contact::class);
        $contact->setData($contactDatas)->save();
        if($contact->save()){
             $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You saved the data.'));
        }else{
             $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Data was not saved.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/index');
    }

}
}
```

**Hope it Helps.**

Comment: Thank you it Works

Comment: glad I could help.

Comment: can you tell me that how foreign data will be saved?

Comment: you need to ask a separate question for that and add code to that question.